# Sampling within a 0/1 matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sampling

I have a $N$x$N$ matrix $G$ composed of zeros and ones. I would like to resample only the ones in $G$ from a Bernoulli distribution where probability $p$ varies along the raws. The idea is to replace all ones in $G$ with realizations from independent Bernoulli variables. I have tried this in *R* :

```
for(i in 1:N){ 
for(j in 1:N){ 
G[i,j] <- ifelse(G[i,j] == 1,rbinom(1,1,p[i]),0)}}
```

However, for computation time, it would be better to avoid the use of for loops. Would anyone know how to write this in matrix form ? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't follow--if you resample "only the ones", then why shouldn't you get only a set of ones??  Could you clarify what you're trying to do?  And in what sense is this code not already in "matrix form"?  Are you trying to say that (1) you want to *replace* all 1's in $G$ with realizations from independent Bernoulli variables and (2) you want to avoid the use of for loops?

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the fuzzy question. Yes for (1) and (2). I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploit `R`'s recycling of vectors and its column-oriented storage.  I'll explain after showing one solution.

```
#
# Generate a 0/1 matrix `G` for testing.
#
N <- 1e3
G <- matrix(rbinom(N^2, 1, 1/2), N)
#
# Generate the vector of probabilities for testing.
#
p <- runif(N)
#
# Here is a solution.
#
U <- runif(N*N) <= p # Random 0/1 values
G.0 <- G * U         # Conditionally replace elements of G
```

The `runif` function generates one uniform variate for each entry in `G`.  Comparing it to the vector `p` creates N vectors of 0/1 values (1 for true, 0 for false), all strung together, with the expected frequency of ones in locations i, i+N, i+2N, ..., i+(N-1)N given by the value of `p[i]` for i=1, 2, ..., N.  When this is multiplied by `G` in the last line, the new values are zeros when either the old value was zero or the new one is, which is the desired result because the values of `G` internally are also laid out column by column.

This solution is about 20 times faster than the original double for loop.  It avoids the slowness of conditional execution (`ifelse`) and exploits any internal parallelism and optimization of `R`'s basic operations (`runif`, `<=`, and `*`).  You do pay a (relatively small) price: RAM to store these random results (here explicitly placed into array `U`) is needed.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If using Python is not off the table, use Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
G = np.array([[0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,1,1,0], [1,1,1,1]])  
# This constructs G row-by-row 
probs = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])  # Replace with your row-wise probabilities
samples = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=probs, size=(4,4))  # Binomial with n=1 is Bernoulli
desired_matrix = np.multiply(G, samples)
```

The `np.multiply` function multiplies arrays element-wise so the zero entries stay zero and the 1 entries are multiplied by either 0 or 1 depending on the realization returned by `np.random.binomial`. One sticking point is that I *believe* that Numpy is smart enough to broadcast each probability in `probs` to the right row when `size` is specified, but I'm not sure because the docs don't mention it.